# With Promtail, how do I only keep log messages for specified Docker containers

Tags: logging, grafana-loki, promtail

So I have configuration like this:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: flog_scrape
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        refresh_interval: 5s
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
        regex: '/(.*)'
        target_label: 'container'
```

It is all good and well, but on the target machine I have interesting containers and garbage containers, and I only want logs from containers called interesting_*something*

What do I do to drop all lines whose container label does not start with "interesting_" / does not match "interesting_.*"?

I've found ways to drop label "container" conditionally; I've also found ways to filter log messages based on their content; I've also found a way to drop labels later on the pipeline stage; but I've NOT found any way to filter/keep/drop entire log line based on label contents yet, that's why I'm asking.

Adding to that I am bitten constantly by the error "pipeline stage must contain only one key" - of which there are [many reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65032914/36498) explaining how it is really a YAML indenting error yet never describing what is the actual formatting solution is. So really I'm looking for a solution which will work when copied verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of interesting containers were brought by a single docker-compose in my case, I've just filtered `docker_sd_configs` by docker-compose project name:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: flog_scrape
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        refresh_interval: 1s
        filters:
          - name: label
            values: ['com.docker.compose.project=chronicle-web']
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
        regex: '/(.*)'
        target_label: 'container'
    pipeline_stages:
      - static_labels: # Needs four whitespace indentation below, will complain otherwise
          host: ${VMHOST} # Env var defined externally, passed via -config.expand-env=true
```

Still have no idea if it has a Pipeline solution.

Comment: Thanks for this one. A couple of other things I've found. 1, I tried specifying multiple labels in the array, but that didn't work. Maybe it is ANDing them together, but I needed ORing. Also, this isn't a regex.

Second note, I also tried using `relabel_config` to `action: keep/drop` but this didn't work. Probably a rookie misunderstanding, but worth flagging as a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved something similar by filtering according to the container name:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: docker
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        filters:
          - name: name
            # Filter logging to just our containers
            values: ["cosmos-openc3-*"]
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ["__meta_docker_container_name"]
        regex: "/(.*)"
        target_label: "container"
```

You can also filter by label:

```
    filters:
      - name: label
        values: ["logging=promtail"]
```

Which requires the following in your docker:

```
services:
  nginx-app:
    container_name: nginx-app
    image: nginx
    labels:
      logging: "promtail"
```

Based my solution on the Promtail docs: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/configuration/#docker_sd_config
which list the available filtering options: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerList